# What is the MLE $\theta^*$ of $\theta$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, cumulative-distribution-functions, robust-statistics

I have that $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ are from a rv $X$ that has the density function $f_X(x)=\frac{2x}{\theta^2} \quad$ for $0 \le x \le \theta  \quad$ and $f_X(x)=0 \quad$ otherwise. Ihave to determine the MLE of $\theta^*$ of $\theta$ 
Here is how I have done it: 
$L(\theta)= \frac{2}{\theta^{2n}}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$ 
$\frac{\partial L(\theta)}{\partial \theta} =...=\frac{-4n}{\theta^{2n+1}}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i + \frac{2}{\theta^{2n}}\frac{\partial(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)}{\partial \theta}$ 
Is this correct? and also how do I calculate the CDF $F_{\theta^*}$, the pdf $f_{\theta^*}$ and the expectation $E[\theta^*]$ of the maximum likelihood estimator $\theta^*$?

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood you wrote is wrong. You did not consider that the support of $X$ depends on $\theta$

The correct likelihood is

$$L(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\theta^{2n}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[x_{(n)};\infty)}(\theta)$$

now, looking at your L, it is evident that it is strictly decreasing, thus

$$\hat{\theta}_{ML}=X_{(n)}$$

where $X_{(n)}$ is the max of the observations

---

Distribution of Max

Set $Z=max(X_i)$

$$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(X_1\leq z,\dots X_n\leq z)=P(X_1\leq z)\dots P(X_n \leq z)=$$

$$=[P(X_1\leq z)]^ n$$

---

To find the distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{ML}=X_{(n)}$ consider that the CDF of Max is the product of the single CDF's thus

$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt=\frac{1}{\theta^2}\int_0^x 2t dt=\frac{x^2}{\theta^2}$$

Thus, setting $Z=\hat{\theta}$ you get

$$F_Z(z)=\frac{z^{2n}}{\theta^{2n}}$$

derivating you get the density and then calculate the expectation with the usual definition

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{d}{dz}F_Z=\frac{2n z^{2n-1}}{\theta^{2n}}$$

$$E(Z)=\int_0^\theta z f_Z(z)dz$$

Comment: I think I get the idea. Could you help me with the second part of the question?

Comment: @MariaFernandez:  as per independence the CDF of max(X) is the product of the X-CDF's. Can you proceed by yourself?

Comment: Im stuck with the symbol after $L(\theta)$. What does that formula even mean?. For the second part: But I dont have any CDF, what product do I have to consider?

Comment: @MariaFernandez : the symbol I used is "is proportional to" because the likelihoods are equivalent but a multiplicative constant. $2^n\Pi_i X_i$ can be considered as a constant thus it is redundant for your calculations.

Comment: Oh I think I get that now. For the second part, could you clearify a little bit more?

Comment: @MariaFernandez : added all the detail to complete the solution by yourself

Comment: I got even more confused now. Why do you have that $F_X(x)=... $ where do you get that from? and how do you get $F_Z(z)$? I am so confused now

Comment: @MariaFernandez : F(x) is the integral function of f(x). $F_{\theta^*}$ is $(F(x))^n$ and $Z$ is any letter you prefer to indicate a rv

Comment: how do you know $F_{\theta^*} = (F_{X})^n$ and also why do you have both $z$ and $\theta$ in CDF for $\theta^*$. To calculate the pdf I need to derivate, but with respect to what? $z$ or $\theta$?

Comment: @MariaFernandez   I added all the details but these are very basic info that you have to know at this point....